# Adding roads to SKMaps

Tags: android, skmaps

I was wondering if there was a way to edit Skobbler maps (online or through some kind of software) and then use the resulting map in my project? For example, could I add a trail which is not in currently in OSM? I sent a message to the Skobbler support team, but have not received a reply.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Scout SDK uses OpenStreetMap as a map data source – the OSM maps are processed to our proprietary format (.skm). Add your map data that is missing in OSM and this will be picked up when we reprocess our maps (each release contains updated maps)

Another possibility to create a certain trail could be to use the custom routing feature: create a route based on a custom GPX file or by specifying an array of points as input. See more details here:
http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/creating-routes-from-gps-points-gpx-track-navigation/